# Definition of self dual function

Tags: functions, logic

I understand the following definition of self dual function:

> A boolean function $f$ is called self dual iff $f=f^d$

I [came across](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/digital-logic-self-dual-functions/) this definition:

> A Switching function or Boolean function is said to be Self dual if:
>
> - The given function is neutral i.e., (number of min terms is equal to the number of max terms).
> - The function does not contain two mutually exclusive terms.

I want to know if this is possible definition or the web page is simply trying to specify properties of self dual function. That is, if any given boolean function satisfying above two conditions, will it be self dual? Are those two conditions necessary and self sufficient for a given boolean function to be a self dual?

Comment: It talks about 1's complement. So don't apply de Morgan’s law as X, Y and Z are bits, not variables. Complement of 000=111.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.